# Hudson and Clover Plugin

Tags: hudson, hudson-plugins, clover

We are using the Clover plugin on Hudson.
Is it possible to set a property on hudson to exclude certain files / packages from being analyzed by clover?
I was looking at the project documentation but didnt come across anything in relation to properties

Thanks
Damien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Maven?  If so, I think Hudson (or Jenkins) will be use the maven plugin configuration to determine which classes to exclude.  You simply configure a set of RegEx expressions that you want to exclude from instrumentation.  In a similar way to the example below:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-clover2-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      </includes>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>**/*Test/java</exclude>
        [...]
      </excludes>
     [...]
</plugin>
```

Hope that helps you out...